# For Spring Boot REST APIs protected by OAuth 2, how to intercept access tokens before forwarding a request to a method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

For a Spring Boot based web application serving REST APIs protected by OAuth 2, how to intercept access tokens before forwarding a request to a method?

In details,

The application is enabled as a resource server by `@EnableResourceServer`, and its API is protected by OAuth 2 (specifically, Cloud Foundry User Account and Authentication).

Now for any request to a method with `@RequestMapping`, it requires an access token obtained from OAuth 2. For example,

> curl -H "Authorization: Bearer [token]" [api]

To achieve fine-grained access control,

Upon a request's arrival, I would like to parse the access token, and based the content of the access token (specifically, `Scope`) forward or deny the request to go forward, hopefully, in a central place (perhaps kind of `Inteceptor`). How to achieve that?

Comment: Shouldn't Spring Security already do that?

Comment: Spring oauth is already doing so for you. But still if you want to intercept it, then you can use your custom filter before BasicAuthenticationFilter

Comment: @dunni Yeah. I would like to have more-fine grained control.

Comment: @Afridi Is there any difference for before and after?

Comment: @DanteisnotaGeek actually all authentication related to oauth token are done in BasicAuthenticationFilter, so in case if authentication fails, this activity execution will be terminated and so your custom filter will not be called. So in case if you want to call your filter in any case, then you have to register your custom filter before BasicAuthenticationFilter

Comment: @DanteisnotaGeek Are you trying to do custom _authentication_ (who is the caller?) or _authorization_ (given that it is JoJo Mojo calling, is JoJo Mojo allowed to do what s/he is asking to do?) checking? If _authentication_, isn't Spring already adequately authenticating the caller for you?  If _authorization_, then (and I'm interested in the answer here) where, when using Spring Security for OAuth2, is the appropriate point to do authorization checking - in the called method?  and How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom filter before authentication

e.g.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(
          new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter